# How do i delete single record from table using EF 6.1.1

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am using `Entity Framework 6.1.1.`

I am `deleting single record from table` as following but i am not sure whether its the only way or could further rewrite it in an efficient way.

Can someone share comments?

**Reason**: I am asking because many solutions in earlier posts are referring to EF 4.0 and not using the latest version 6.1.1.

```
Guid studentId = student.Id;
StudentReportDetail stuDetails = _context.StudentReportDetail.Find(studentId);
if (stuDetails != null)
{
    _context.StudentReportDetail.Remove(stuDetails);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are no changes about how to delete an entity between EF 4 and EF 6. To delete an entity using Entity Framework, you need to use the `Remove` method on `DbSet`. `Remove` works for both *existing and newly added entities*.

- Calling `Remove` on an entity that has been added but not yet saved
  to the database will cancel the addition of the entity. The entity is
  removed from the change tracker and is no longer tracked by the
  `DbContext`.
- Calling `Remove` on an existing entity that is being change-tracked
  will register the entity for deletion the next time `SaveChanges` is
  called.

**Deleting with loading from the database**

As the example you show in your question, you need to load first the existing entity from your context to delete it. If you don't know the `Id`, you can execute a query as I show below to find it first:

```
    var report= (from d in context.StudentReportDetail
               where d.ReportName == "Report"
               select d).Single();

    context.StudentReportDetail.Remove(report);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

**Deleting without loading from the database**

If you need to delete an entity, but it’s not already in memory, it’s a little inefficient to retrieve that entity from the database just to delete it. If you know the key of the entity you want to delete, you can attach a *stub* that represents the entity to be deleted, and then delete this *stub*. A *stub* is an instance of an entity that just has the key value assigned. *The key value is all that’s required for deleting entities*.

```
var toDelete = new StudentReportDetail {Id = 2 };

context.StudentReportDetail.Attach(toDelete);
context.StudentReportDetail.Remove(toDelete);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Other way could be changing the entity's state to `Deleted`.`DbContext` has methods called `Entry` and `Entry<TEntity>`, these methods get a `DbEntityEntry` for the given entity and provide access to the information about the entity and return a `DbEntityEntry` object able to perform the action on the entity. Now you can perform the delete operation on the context by just changing the entity state to `EntityState.Deleted`:

```
var toDelete = new StudentReportDetail {Id = 2 };
context.Entry(toDelete).State = EntityState.Deleted;  
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Using a 3rd party library**

There is another way but is using a 3rd party library, [EntityFramework Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus), there is a nugget package you can install. You can use the batch delete operation:

```
context.StudentReportDetail
    .Where(u => u.Id== stuDetails)
    .Delete();
```

Comment: thanks foe explanation. How about "modelBuilder.Entity<Principle>().HasOptional(x => x.Dependant).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete() in context initialiaztion class".. Which one is better?

Comment: your above explanation for my posted question is excellent and made my concept very clear Going forward, i am confirming another point in my above comments regarding "Cascade deletion for 1-1 relationship". I think that would be nice solution to perform cascading deletion. For normal deletion your answer is excellent and i am very clear about it. What would you say about practice for cascade deletion?

Comment: the only problem here is that an exception is thrown if an entity with the given id does not exist in the db. Is there a way around that? Otherwise I would need to do something like context.Any(x => x.Id = id) beforehand, which would defeat the object of this.

Comment: @DanO'Leary, I added another way to do it

Comment: that looks great, although it's been deprecated in favour of this now though: http://entityframework-plus.net/?z=ef-extended